# “Answer your own question” checkbox has some weird styling

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, self-answer

Text style for "Answer your own question" under the "Post Your Question" button on the [asking page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) is weird:

> [image]

In particular link text is smaller than the beginning of the sentence, and slightly shifted to the top.

In my expectation all letters in that sentence should be same size and have same vertical position point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, presumably as part of the new ask page introduced in 2020: [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/295232)

[image]