# When you get the "Your question is ready to publish", allow submitting it from that modal instead of moving to the bottom of the page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, asking-questions

As described in [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/209901), all new questions now go through a workflow that finally leads to the pleasant announcement "Your question is ready to publish!":

[image]

I would expect the UI to show a button "submit" just below that box. However, you need to go all the way down to the question to click in "Post your question":

[image]

For this, would it be possible to have a button just below the text to allow posting the question? Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize that time and thought was put into this request, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.

Comment: You tagged it declined, so you disagree that it is a good idea? Or would you consider it a good idea but just not plan on implementing it, which would make it status-deferred?

Comment: [status-declined] is not meant to be a permanent sentence that the request will _never_ get implemented, just that we _definitely_ don't have any plans of doing it in the foreseeable future. The tag description does end with "at present time" ;)

Comment: @JNat but how do you all use it? Do you periodically review declined requests? Or do they go into the junk heap?

Comment: @JNat that present time part only applies to the bug part of the tag description seeing how that sentence is constructed.

Comment: Also the tag description for status-deferred states: "Indicates that the feature request or bug has merit to consider, but will not be implemented or fixed in the near term." So if something is not deferred, but declined one could reason a FR has no merit.

Comment: Read through the "And other old posts that fall outside of the scope of projects being worked on?" section on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/208518), @muru — we don't periodically review these, but invite folks to re-post and re-escalate declined stuff when something significant (such as a roadmap) has changed.

Comment: One could reason that, indeed, @Luuklag — that's why Anita posted this answer, so you didn't need to make such inferences and were instead given a clear reason for the request to have been declined ;)