# Is the "review your question" page expected to be beneficial if none of the detectable warnings are triggered?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

As per [this announcement of the new ask page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network) 2 months ago (March 2020): after you've written your question, you are taken to a 2nd page which prompts you to "Review your question".

There are 2 possibilities when you land on that page:

- either your question has "obvious" validation failures.
- or it successfully passes validation.

In the former case, the page is clearly beneficial, in that it provides a nice UX for understanding what needs to be fixed (especially if you're new to the site, and aren't familiar with the form).

But in the latter case, I offer that it doesn't add anything. As far as I can tell, it has all the same information as the previous page:

- You could already see a pre-render of your question.
- You could already see a list of various Similar Questions.

As far as I can tell, it just forces me to click the same button twice; adding annoying UX for no benefit.

---

It might be a prompt for new users to encourage them to *actually* use the above features.

It might perhaps be intended as a mental prompt to get people to reflect on their question? But I'd honestly be surprised if it were actually achieving that, rather than *everyone* ignoring it and auto-clicking "Post".

Do we have server-log evidence of how long people spend on the "Review" page? Conversely is there any evidence of questions getting "lost" because people forget to click twice?

---

If there *is* some new info on that page, then it needs a re-design in order to make that clear!
If not, we should gather evidence to assess its efficacy.
If it does nothing (as I suspect), then I offer that it's a pointless irritation and should be removed.

Comment: For users that are less asking savvy that step will show all kind of warnings / errors and guidance on how to fix that.

Comment: @rene what do you mean by warnings and errors? How can there be a (detectable) error on a question?

Comment: @Brondahl length, missing code markup, tags that shouldn't be used on their own. And now at least there is a proper place to expand and extend on that. In the prior design you had to squeeze everything in a tiny popup.

Comment: @Brondahl see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCY47.png). Essentially,  same errors as before, just displayed in a more useful and friendly way.

Comment: I have some more detailed concrete suggestions, which I'd expect to post as 'answers' to be discussed. Is that correct, or should I include them in the 'question 'itself?

Comment: @Brondahl cheers, though now it might be dupe of something else - this time not my call, can't close again anyway. If you have ideas, then yes feel free to post them as answers, either here or in the dupe.

Comment: @Glorfindel, I can definitely see why you've marked this as a dupe of the other question. In a sense it's a dupe, but I'd argue that my question has been asked in good faith to try to understand what's going on, and offering some reasonable theories as to why that page exists. Whereas the "dupe" appears to just be whining about a page they don't like with no intention to be productive. I think that's supported by the incredibly sarcastic answer it has (one that I rather feel is reasonable given the presentation of the question).

Comment: @Brondahl no problem. It's just that the original indicates 'it's being reviewed by staff' and that probably means things are going to change, which could even solve your issues. Using this post to gather some ideas is fine with me.

Answer (score 5):

On the assumption that the data doesn't support having the page for all users (or that the data doesn't exist) and that there's no outpouring of opinion that the page *is* actively helping experienced users ...

I suggest two possible changes. Separate answers to allow for distinct conversations:

---

**Make that page only appear when there are actually validation errors.**

This is only relevant if we think that even new users don't benefit from the additional page unless there are validation errors.

In that case ... if there are no validation errors, just immediately post the question, and only use that review page if there ARE errors.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the data doesn't support having the page for all users (or that the data doesn't exist) and that there's no outpouring of opinion that the page *is* actively helping experienced users ...

I suggest two possible changes. Separate answers to allow for distinct conversations:

---

**Make that page only appear for new users**

We already have a variety of features that are rep-dependent. Mostly they're *additional* features and functionality, but I can't imagine that *removing* some functionality can be that much harder?

So once you've reached ***N*** reputation, that page no-longer appears, prompting you to Review your Question. It is assumed that you're already fully familiar with the form and with the community expectations.

Perhaps this is combined with my other suggestion of having the page exist if there are trivial validation errors, so that if an experienced user posts a valid question it's one-click, but if you're new or you screwed up the form, then it takes 2 clicks.

Comment: I thought it was already for new users only...