# A link where the content of the ask-page modal dialog can be seen

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, asking-questions

Not too long ago, the new modal dialog displayed to users who were asking their first questions was added. The relevant announcement can be seen here: [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513)

Before that, the page located at `/questions/ask/advice` was displayed to the users asking their first question on *some* sites.<sup>1</sup> For example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice

One advantage of having this link was that the information displayed to first-time askers could be seen by a regular users simply by entering a link. In this way, it was possible to give this link also to users who have missed it when they posted the first question.

Moreover, it was easier to get some input in which way this information could be customized - a regular user could see it at any time. I might have missed something, but I did not find a way to display this modal window other than creating a new user, just for the purpose of viewing this information (or taking a screenshot).

**Question:** Is there a link where the content of this modal window (displayed for the first-time askers) can be accessed? If not, could such a link be added?

---

<sup>1</sup> I am aware of [Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5850/should-folks-have-to-click-through-an-interstitial-page-to-ask-questions-on-serv) and [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/show-how-to-ask-advice-before-a-new-user-asks-a-question), but it is quite likely that it was displayed also on some other sites.

Comment: I'll just add that if somebody wants to discuss the customization of this text, they'll probably be willing to do the effort, created a new account and get the text in that way. However, if it's easy to make the same text accessible, I think that it might be useful in such situation.

Answer (score 4):

There's actually two ways to add information to the new ask question modal. If we add it to the space after "we've provided some guidance:" - then it still appears on that page you've linked to. You can see with Code Review, which we just updated in September of 2020.

The modal looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the "asking a good question" modal on Code Review]

And their [ask advice page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) contains the same customized content.

We can also add a paragraph right before the bulleted list - this is a text-only paragraph with formatting abilities similar to comments (links, bold, italics only). This content, however *isn't* reflected on that page. As an example, the [Science Fiction & Fantasy modal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and [their ask advice page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice). While we don't have a specific way to see this on site, you can view it in most cases by visiting the ask page in an incognito or private browsing window. The only time this won't work is on sites that require registration to ask a question.