# Redirect new user to the help, 'How to ask' page. So that there are fewer bad questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, question-quality

Redirect new user to the help, 'How to ask' page. So, that there are less bad questions.

Me, myself made a bad mistake of asking non-security questions on https://security.stackexchange.com/.

And, I realise there are only four moderators there.

So, when a user registers on a new site on the Stack Exchange network, then just first show them a welcome page, or redirect them to the 'How to ask' page of the site.

If there is not a good 'How to ask' page, then let us, *the community* create it for the site :) Or at least, I will be happy to help in that matter :)

### FAQ

***No one reads anything?***
Make them read it, by just adding like a 10-20 seconds cooldown period before they can browse the site. Give them 5-10 rep for reading it for the first time, for example, or just give them a badge that they get for reading the help page patiently.

### Edit:

Why did I make that mistake in *Information Security*? 
What I thought was: 
Any question about SSL => Information Security. 
But, that assumption was wrong.

Comment: *Or just give them a badge that they get for reading the help page patiently.* You mean something similar to the [informed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed) badge?

Comment: This was used on some sites, such as [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/show-how-to-ask-advice-before-a-new-user-asks-a-question) or [Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5850/should-folks-have-to-click-through-an-interstitial-page-to-ask-questions-on-serv). In 2020, a modal window for the first-time askers was introduced, which replaces this mechanism: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513

Answer (score 7):

Low friction to posting is a core tenet of Stack Exchange, presumably as a reaction to the excesses of [the hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange).

> Me, myself made a bad mistake of asking non-security questions on https://security.stackexchange.com/.

You probably have less of an excuse than most, unless it was before you found meta, but it isn't incredibly hard to figure out what a site is for.

[image]

The site header is the tiniest bit of a giveaway, as is spending time looking at the front page.

The big problem with help is - you need to spend a bit of a time investment, and let’s be real here... who actually spends time reading about and help pages?

On the other hand, presupposing this was a while ago, the slightly improved question page is a perfect place for a precis of the precise purpose of a site.

[image]

Personally it could do with a little polish, but if you aren't even asking yourself 'What is information security, and is my question on this', we might have to break out the big guns... blink and marquee tags.

Comment: Bonus points for correct usage of "precis".

Comment: Can we please get neon Star Wars effect that displays the help center content?  I think that’s the only way it will be read at times