# How do the tag warnings work in the "Review your question" sidebar?

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions, new-users, tag-warnings

About a year ago, the [new ask question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network) was rolled out. The meta post states that sites can customize the review pane in various ways. Some of those ways include warnings for the body of the post or its tags.

It's stated that they are "regex-based". However, this could mean any number of things:

- The regex is matched against each tag individually (i.e., `code-golf` then `math` then `number`)
- The regex is matched against a string containing each tag, with some delimiter (i.e., `code-golf math number`)
- The regex is matched against the actual text in the input

Am I misunderstanding how the tag warnings work, or if not, what are the regexes matched against?

Comment: See https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12938/134009, there's a bit on the regex-based tag warnings there.