# Is the algorithm which reviews questions when one clicks "review your question" customizable on a per-site basis?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, asking-questions, new-users

Since at least a few years ago (I cannot locate the announcement of this feature's introduction) most SE sites require at least two clicks to post a question -- first, one clicks the "Review your question" button, and then it turns into "Post your question", and it can be clicked for publication. In between, one gets feedback on the right of the screen which says things like "Your question is ready to be submitted".

Is it possible to customize the algorithm for this feedback on a per-site basis? For instance, on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), our most common type of off-topic question is homework questions. But when I write a question titled "Please help me with my homework!!!", the system doesn't tell me my question looks problematic. It would be nice if "homework" could be a keyword, where, if it appears in the question, the feedback will be something like "Your question may be off-topic for this site, consider asking somewhere else.", outlined in yellow or orange rather than green (I'd imagine the user would still be *allowed* to post the question, just advised that it may not be suitable.) As it is, the feedback may be giving users a *false* sense of confidence about the suitability of their questions.

(Of course, that's not to say that all homework questions actually contain the word "homework", nor that all off-topic questions on MO are homework questions, but it would be nice to catch some of these easy cases.)

Other sorts of generic things which could be checked are whether the title is in all-caps, whether sentences start with capital letters, etc.

P.S. Any tagging help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I guess that the announcement that there now exists the "review your question" part of the process was made here: [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513) (March 2020)

Comment: @Martin Thanks! As you pointed out to me elsewhere, it appears that the answer to my question is (least a qualified) _yes_: the post you linked even shows an example from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where the "algorithm" I refer to (which is regex-based) has apparently been customized and a custom message is shown to the user. I am pleasantly surprised!

Comment: Martin also suggested to me elsewhere that customizations used at Code Review appear to have likely originated from [this meta question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/code-review-clippy?). Good to know for anybody looking to implement something similar.