# Could the search link in the modal window be customizable?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

As announced [in March 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network), there is now a modal window which is displayed for the first-time askers. Some parts are customizable per-site:

> **The "welcome modal" for new askers** (seen with the default text in screenshot 1), everything between the title and "Before you post..."

This modal window contains the text: "Before you post, [search the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) to make sure your question hasn’t been answered." In this text the "search the site" is a link which currently goes to the page `/search` of the specific site.

Some Stack Exchange sites could have specific guidelines for searching. (For example, they might have collected a list of FAQs or a description of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on their meta.) Or they might even use a different search engine customized for the topic of that site. So maybe it would make sense to link to something site-specific.

**Proposal.** Make also this link in the modal window customizable per-site.

---

I made this post with my own feature request on Mathematics Meta in mind: [Change the link to search in modal window for the first-time askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32973). (There are some search engines which are useful when searching for math formulas - it is understandable that such tools might be useful when searching on a Q&A site which is primarily about mathematics.)

<s>So far the only confirmation I have that it is not customizable was a [message from a CM in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57753055#57753055) when a MathOverflow moderator asked [about the target of this link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57751587#57751587).</s> EDIT: In the meantime, the feature request on Mathematics Meta [got an answer from a CM](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32973/change-the-link-to-search-in-modal-window-for-the-first-time-askers/33499#33499). So this could be considered as an official confirmation that it is not customizable at the moment.

Comment: It seems to me that the current hyperlink is almost never appropriate (and so the fact that it is not customizable is doubly irksome). Every page on SE _has_ a search bar; the page being linked to merely lists all of the search keywords you can add, with zero explanation of what is going on (and in addition continues to have the little search bar at the top of the screen). When you factor in that this is being linked to for _first-time askers_, it seems like a joke, really --they are unlikely to be using these keywords anyway. So sending them to this link is intimidating and counterproductive.

Comment: At the very least, perhaps it'd be better linking to [`/help/searching`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) as the default instead of [`/search`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search)...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. That seems like a reasonable suggestion - at least the link would go to something that is customizable per site. Maybe you could post your suggestion as an answer? (In that way other users can upvote/downvote that suggestion and add comments.)